# I should make a program to sort struct array but I don't have any idea to do this

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, bubble-sort

after editing

---

the code is :

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct names//defining struct array with leinght of (3) 
{
char firstname[50];
char lastname[50];
int age;
}n[4];

void show(struct names n[],int);//print the struct elements on the screen
void sortbyage(struct names n[],int);//sort the struct elements by age

int main(void)
{
    struct names n[4];
    int len=3;

    strcpy(n[0].firstname,"david");
    strcpy(n[0].lastname,"bekham");
    n[0].age=18;
    strcpy(n[1].firstname,"cristiano");
    strcpy(n[1].lastname,"ronaldo");
    n[1].age=20;
    strcpy(n[2].firstname,"iron");
    strcpy(n[2].lastname,"man");
    n[2].age=16;
    show(n,len);
    sortbyage(n,len);
    show(n,len);

    return 0;
}
void show(struct names n[],int len)
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%d-first name ==>%s\n",i+1,n[i].firstname);
        printf("%d-last name ==>%s\n",i+1,n[i].lastname);
        printf("%d-age==>%i\n",i+1,n[i].age);
    }
}
void sortbyage(struct names n[],int len)
{
   // int help=0;
    for(int i=len-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(n[j].age>n[j+1].age)
            {
                n[4]=n[j];
                n[j]=n[j+1];
                n[j+1]=n[4];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

after Editing it works

---

note : in run time it types in the last line this message : *** process returned -1073741819 ***)) how could I fix this and does it a big problem or it's don't matter???

Comment: Seems you have the general idea about using structures. Just have some basic typos. So go through and review carefully the lines of code that the error messages point to. Mainly typos like this: `n.age[j]>n.age[j+1]` should be `n[j].age>n[j+1].age`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access as follows. Please modify your code some thing as below

```
if(n[j].age > n[j+1].age)
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Please modify the sortbyage() function as follows and it is working fine.

```
void sortbyage(struct names n[],int len)
{
    struct names temp;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
        {
            if(n[i].age > n[j].age)
            {
                temp = n[i];
                n[i] = n[j];
                n[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works thanks but I had edited the length of the struct array to (4) and I wrote the code like this :                                                      for(int i=len-1;i>0;i--)
 {
  for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
  {
   if(n[j].age>n[j+1].age)
   {
    n[4]=n[j];
    n[j]=n[j+1];
    n[j+1]=n[4];
   }
  }
 }
 in run time it works but in the last line it type this for me : ((***process returned -1073741819 ***)) how could I fix this ???

Comment: @mahmoudzeno I have updated the answer as per the requiement please check.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
if(n[j].age>n[j+1].age)
{
    help=n[j].age;
    n[j].age=n[j+1].age;
    n[j+1].age=help;
}
```